# When I use lldb in a swift project, I can't modify the bool value

Tags: swift

help me, please, I'm new to Swift.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        var flag = false     
        print(" current->  \(flag)") /** Add a breakpoint  **/
        if flag == true {
            print(" after  -> true")
        }else {
            print(" after ->   false")
        }
    }
```

I want to use lldb to modify the value of 'flag', so,

```
(lldb) po flag
false

(lldb) expression flag = true
(lldb) po flag
true

(lldb) continue
2018-11-24 23:57:05.552804+0800 test_swift_lldb[6806:384106] XPC connection interrupted
Process 6806 resuming
 current->  false
 after ->   false
```

It doesn't seem to be useful.
Please tell me how to use lldb, modify the bool value.

Comment: Hi, please enter you code as text and not as an external image.  You are trying to use the debugger, correct?  See if this answer helps with entering debugger commands: [how-to-change-variables-value-while-debugging-with-llvm-in-xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907387/how-to-change-variables-value-while-debugging-with-llvm-in-xcode)

Comment: @Bill Do you have any good ideas? I was frustrated by this problem...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems to be an issue between Swift and LLDB.  I suspect that Swift is optimizing the var flag away into a register.  There are a couple of other SO questions on a similar problem, for instance: [Why is Xcode's Variables View's “Edit Value” not changing the variable value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367005/why-is-xcodes-variables-views-edit-value-not-changing-the-variable-value). Interestingly, Xcode somehow works around this problem.  The work-around seems to be to "trick" LLDB into recognizing the the variable is updated.  I modified your code as follows:

```
//
//  main.swift
//  debug_example
//

import Foundation

print("Hello, main")
var flag = false
var debugString = "abcd"
if debugString.count == 0 { flag = true }

print(" current->  \(flag)") /** Add a breakpoint  **/
if flag == true {
    print(" after  -> true")
}else {
    print(" after ->   false")
}
```

The following are my LLDB commands simplified (output indented):

```
lldb main
breakpoint set --line 8
process launch
    Process 64052 launched:
po flag
    false
ex flag=true
po flag
    true
s
    Hello, World!
    Target 0: (main) stopped.
po flag
    false
ex flag=true
po flag
    true
thread continue
    Resuming thread
    current->  true
    after  -> true
```

Perhaps someone else can provide more information or some insight into how Xcode works around this.

Comment: Wow, it works. But,when i am coding, I will not write those codes to 'trick' lldb, Because those codes have no meaning for the project...

Comment: I completely agree.  I just cleaned out some older versions of llvm and related components.  I have `lldb --version showing: lldb-1000.11.38.2 Swift-4.2`.  Now everything works as you would expect; no tricks required.  Check your versions of swiftc and lldb.

Comment: I am ashamed to ask you, My current xcode configuration is
  lldb --version showing: lldb-1000.11.38.2 Swift-4.2。 But  When I run my initial code for this question,   it was not work... What caused it?        
     <code>
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        var flag = false     
        print(" current->  \(flag)") /** Add a breakpoint  **/
        if flag == true {
            print(" after  -> true")
        }else {
            print(" after ->   false")
        }
    }</code>

Comment: Perhaps backup a bit.  Create a very, very simple project like the sample code above.  If you have Xcode installed, try if from there.  Xcode uses lldb.  Next try it from the command line:  swiftc -g main.swift followed by lldb main.  Like I mentioned, when I removed old versions of lldb, it worked for me.